# How can I make scroll bar mouse areas go all the way to edge of the screen on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, mouse, scrolling, scrollbar

Windows 11 shows scrollbars with a margin between them and the edge of the screen.  This makes it hard to grab, especially for people with mobility issues.

A simple fix would be to allow grabbing the scrollbar all the way to the edge - either by drawing it there, or just by extending the active mouse area to the edge.

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can .....  allow grabbing the scrollbar all the way to
> the edge

Most likely not.

However, you can make scroll bars wider which is the way this problem is normally addressed. This is, I think, the easiest way to make the scrollbars easier to grab.

[Wide Scroll bars](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/change_scrollbar_size.html#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20Registry%20Editor.&text=Look%20for%20ScrollHeight%20or%20ScrollWidth,to%20%2D1500%20(larger).)

> One cool hidden feature of Windows that shouldn't be is the ability to
> change the width and height of scrollbars in Windows 10 & 11.
>
> We should note that the scrollbars won't change in modern UI apps,
> including Settings, Start Menu, or Windows Store apps.
>
> You also have to edit the registry, so make a backup first.
>
> Navigate to: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control
> Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
>
> Look for ScrollHeight or ScrollWidth on the right. The default value
> is -252.
>
> You can enter a number from -120 (smaller) to -1500 (larger).
>
> If you want to set a specific pixel size, use -15 x the width you want
> in pixels.
>
> For example, the default size of -255 using 17 pixels would be -15x17
> = -255

Using the method in the article, you can adjust Scrollbar Height for horizontal scrollbars and Scrollbar Width for vertical scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks.  What's the difference between ScrollHeight and ScrollWidth? Also, what do you recommend for "modern UI apps"?

Comment: There is a registry key in the article in my answer Scroll Height and another for Scroll Width.

Comment: Yes, but what does setting ScrollHeight do?

Comment: Scroll Height is for horizontal scroll bars and Scroll Width is for vertical scroll bars